# How can I display only one picture as Thumbnail Navigation using Tiny-slider?

Tags: javascript, css, tiny-slider

I am using [Tiny Slider](http://ganlanyuan.github.io/tiny-slider/demo/) with the customization showing Navigation as Thumbnails for one my project.
What I am trying to achive is that the Navigation Thumbnail only show 1 image (the next one after the active slide) instead of all images in store.
Any directions on how I should tackle this? Thank you all in advance for your help?

Answer (score 0):

I figured out the work around for anyone in the future that would have the same problem.
I set the thumbnail in the tns-item and trigger the next button everytime I clicked the image.
Here is the code:

```
jQuery(document).on('click', '.your-thumbnail-pic', function(event) {
event.preventDefault();
jQuery(".slider-next-arrow").click();
});
```